# Send HTTPS Request using SSL Socket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, openssl, traffic

Hi:  I am trying to make a small  HTTPS client program mainly usign JAVA.

Below is the code snippet:

```
SSLSocket result = (SSLSocket) SSLCont.sslSocketFactory.createSocket(
                    sockfd, "www.facebook.com", 443, false);
result.startHandshake(); 
result.getOutputStream().write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.facebook.com\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
String  res=my.getData(result.getInputStream());
print(res);
```

I can print Facebook response properly. There is no issue.

The issue is - when I see the traffic using "TRAFFIC capture" program I see following data  for "TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello." part

```
TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.
. .....ÿÿÿÿ.............ïM©.LoÓ....??ÞÐJd:Ôn..¡.?ÞÐJd:..ªª.....
.E..ë.×@.@.».À¨.eð.$?6.»§.Îç?ç.?P.ý\?-
......¾...º..???v????{3?¯ß.DÅJ.>?÷®ÿ±û*^».8i1...À+À/Ì©Ì¨À,À0À.À.À
.À..3.9./.5.....s.........www.facebook.com....ÿ.
........................#...............................
..........................
```

But when I  open  the website ( www.facebook.com ) directly in Browser say in CHROME,  I see following traffic :

```
TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.
. .....ÿÿÿÿ.............ïM©.LoÓ....??ÞÐJd:Ôn..¡.?ÞÐJd:..ªª.....
.E..ë.×@.@.».À¨.eð.$?6.»§.Îç?ç.?P.ý\?-
......¾...º..???v????{3?¯ß.DÅJ.>?÷®ÿ±û*^».8i1...À+À/Ì©Ì¨À,À0À.À.À
.À..3.9./.5.....s.........www.facebook.com....ÿ.
........................#.........h2.http/1.1...........
..........................
```

If we  compare both traffic data carefully we see ,   in case of Traffic Generated by Chrome browser we  will see  following extra string
**"..h2.http/1.1...."** appended at last ,which tells it is for HTTP and looks perfect.

But this string is not getting appended  in traffic generated  by  my java program.

Can you please tell me  why  "*..h2.http/1.1....*"  string not appearing in traffic generated by my java program. 
How to modify my java code so that the string appears in the request traffic generated by my java program .

Note:  But when I use java inbuilt class "**HttpsURLConnection**"  to open that website  I see "*..h2.http/1.1....*"  is present in traffic. 
This issue is applicable for all HTTPS websites.

Can you please tell me What is missing in my Java code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please tell me why "..h2.http/1.1...." string not appearing in traffic generated by my java program.

First, it it not a good idea to treat a binary protocol (as TLS is) like text when analyzing it. If you would look at the traffic with Wireshark instead and dig deeper in the TLS handshake you see that the client is using [ALPN](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation) to indicate to the server that it does support 'h2' (HTTP/2) and 'http/1.1' (HTTP/1.1). A server supporting HTTP/2 will then probably use this as the protocol for the connection and not HTTP/1.1 since HTTP/2 is more efficient.

> How to modify my java code so that the string appears in the request traffic generated by my java program .

Unless you are able to properly communicate using the HTTP/2 protocol to the server you don't want to tell the server that you can do HTTP/2, i.e. you don't want to add this information with ALPN. Given that you just managed to send a HTTP request but failed to handle the response properly (you expect the server to close the connection after the response although you allow the server to keep the connection open by implicitly enabling HTTP keep-alive with using HTTP/1.1) I doubt that you can do the way more complex HTTP/2 protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This line "result.startHandshake(); "  is generating that traffic. It is the first call by client to server. At this point it does not know any thing about server protocol etc. I wanted to know  why the REQUEST DATA is different in both cases.   Should I  set any parameter before making  result.startHandshake()  call .   Thanks

Comment: When I  am  using HttpsURLConnection  class it is generating that string. It is happening from first request  handshake call.  It means  even I try to connect to a FTP or any other fake  server , the same request data  I will see.

Comment: But the issue is  why my call   result.startHandshake()  not generating request like a Browser or  HttpsURLConnection    does.   May be I need to write few more code before making call  startHandshake();   Please help.

Comment: Yes. I understand.  Can you please tell  me how to to add that information HTTP 1.1   or HTTP 2  in  Client hello/handshake.  I do not see any way as of now.  I see I can only  set CipherSuites etc   Thanks

Comment: @poorcoder: with Java 9 ALPN support is there, see https://de.slideshare.net/martintoshev/java-9-security-enhancements-in-practice slides 22..25. For older versions of Java see http://unrestful.io/2015/10/09/alpn-java.html

Comment: Thanks. Ya.  I just got it . But I have one question.

I am using jdk1.8   and following method "setApplicationProtocols" is not available yet . Fine.

     SSLParameters p = sslSocket.getSSLParameters();
     p.setProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
    
     p.setApplicationProtocols(new String[] {"h2", "http/1.1"});
     sslSocket.setSSLParameters(p);
     
But how  java inbuilt calss "HttpsURLConnection"  in  same jdk 1.8  can add  ALPN inforamtion in Client Hello message?

Thank you

Comment: @poorcoder: With Java9 it is a supported API. With older version you have to dig deeper in the internals. See the link I provided about the older versions and just follow the links to the [implementation in Jetty](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn/tree/master/alpn-boot/src/main/java/sun/security/ssl) to get the details.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Really appreciated .